# How to access to a class member in PyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I wrote the code below in PyGTK:

```
class Window(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        rbtn_one = gtk.RadioButton(label = "One")
        rbtn_two = gtk.RadioButton(label = "Two", group = rbtn_one)
        txt = gtk.Entry()
        btn = gtk.Button("Click")
        fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        fixed.put(rbtn_one, 10, 10)
        fixed.put(rbtn_two, 10, 40)
        fixed.put(txt, 10, 70)
        fixed.put(btn, 10, 100)
        btn.connect("clicked", self.method)

    def method(self, widget):
        txt.get_text() # <-- Help here!
```

I'd like access to members created in the builder since `method`. But I get the message: `NameError: global name 'txt' is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong? What is the best place to define the variables? Should I use properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want txt to be available anywhere in the instance, the easiest way is to assign it to self:

```
self.txt = gtk.Entry()
...
self.txt.get_text()
```